# Can't create row because give null image path on form upload

Tags: php, laravel, image-uploading

I want to upload image and save data on database use form in view, but while press submit button, i get some error that is **Call to a member function hasFile() on null** when I have selected images on my computer, how to the fix that error so that i can upload image and saving data on database. Thanks for you answer.

Here code in controller :

```
public function UploadFile()
    {
        $file = Input::file('image');

        if($file->hasFile('image'))
        {
            $name = $datas->kode_barang.'.jpg';
            $file->move(public_path().'/assets/images/barang/', $name);
            $newpath = public_path().'/assets/images/barang/'.$name;

            $dataGambar = new GambarModel;
            $dataGambar -> kode_gambar   = $datas->kode_barang;
            $dataGambar -> nama_gambar   = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $dataGambar -> path          = $newpath;
            $dataGambar -> kategori      = 'barang';

            $dataGambar->save();

            Session::flash('message', 'Berhasil menambahkan barang !');
            return Redirect::to('/barang');
        }
        else
        {
            Session::flash('message', 'Upload tidak berhasil'.$file->getPathName() );
            return Redirect::to('/barang');
        }
    }
```

Here some script form file on view :

```
{{ Form::label('image', 'Pilih gambar') }}
{{ Form::file('image') }}
```

Comment: did you add enctype="multipart/form-data" in your form tag.

Comment: thanks a lot, i have corrected this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `enctype ="multipart/form-data"` in your form tag.